# Calculating Luhn Algorithm with Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to validate an [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) number with the Help of Stream API in Java 8.

```
private void ValidateIMEI() {
    field //a field holding an IMEI Number
            .getText().chars()
            .map(this::ConvertASCIIToNumer);
}
```

The part I am stuck is the doubling the even number and divide it by 10.

Initially, I tried the traditional for loop:

```
private void ValidateIMEI() {
    int[] numbers = field //a field holding an IMEI Number
            .getText().chars()
            .map(this::ConvertASCIIToNumer).toArray();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        //Double the even number and divide it by 10. add quotient and remainder
        if ((numbers[i]+1) % 2 == 0) {
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] / 10 + numbers[i] % 10;
        }
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    if (sum%10==0) {
        status.setText("Valid");
    }
    else{
        status.setText("InValid");
    }        
}
```

But the code is broken and most specifically using For loop which I don't want.

So, any one can help to implement [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) with only Stream API in Java 8?

Code for ConvertASCIIToNumer:

```
private int ConvertASCIIToNumer(int value) {
    return Character.digit(value, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you double the even numbers when you should be doubling the numbers having even index. Since the index matters in this algorithm, I'd suggest using a `IntStream` of the indices :

```
boolean isValid =
    IntStream.range(0,numbers.length)
             .map (i -> (((i%2) ^ (numbers.length%2)) == 0) ? ((2*numbers[i])/10+(2*numbers[i])%10) : numbers[i])
             .sum() % 10 == 0;
```

Edit : I just changed the condition, since the length of the array determines whether the odd or even indices should be multiplied by 2.

If the array's length is even, the digits in the even indices should be doubled :

```
Index 0 1 2 3 4 5

Digit 1 5 2 5 2 6
      -   -   -
```

If the array's length is odd, the digits in the odd indices should be double :

```
Index 0 1 2 3 4

Digit 1 5 2 5 2
        -   -
```

Comment: woha int can not be converted boolean

Comment: i'd replace a^b == 0 to a == b

Comment: Alternatively you can iterate only to half the length of the `numbers` array and process a pair of digits in every iteration.

Comment: @RiaD Or `(i-numbers.length()) % 2 == 0`. (I know, this overflows for negative `i`s and very long arrays but we happen to know that neither of these is true in our case.)

Answer (score 2):

This is as pretty as I could make it:

```
String num; // your IMEI number
int[] a = {num.length() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2};        // 1 if length even, 2 otherwise
boolean isLuhn = num.chars()
        .map(i -> i - '0')         // convert to the int equivalent
        .map(n -> n * (a[0] = a[0] == 1 ? 2 : 1)) // multiply by 1, 2 alternating
        .map(n -> n > 9 ? n - 9 : n)              // handle sum of digits
        .sum() % 10 == 0;                         // mod 10 should be zero
```

A "trick" used here is using an `int[]`, instead of an `int`, variable to hold the multiplier. This is a work-around for only being allowed to refer to "effectively final" variables; the *array* reference is effectively final, but its *contents* (just one element) is doesn't have to be!

Comment: You don’t need to split into strings when you actually want the `char`s. In other words, don’t use `Arrays.stream(num.split(""))`. All you need is `num.chars().map(c -> c - '0')`…

Comment: @Holger omg... all this time I never noticed that method. Thanks for the lesson :)

Comment: Your ``i`` in the first ``.map()`` conflicts with the variable ``int[] i`` defined above. I get this error: ``Lambda expression's parameter i cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.``

Comment: @maxxyme Ah. I fixed that now. (I usually don't have a compiler handy as most of my code is thumbed in on my phone)